# Parse a string line by opening a file using Regex

Tags: java, regex

This is the below text file(log.txt) I am opening and need to match each line using regular expressions.

```
Jerty|gas|petrol|2.42 
Tree|planet|cigar|19.00
Karie|entertainment|grocery|9.20
```

So I wrote this regular expressions but it is not getting matched.

```
public static String pattern = "(.*?)|(.*?)|(.*?)|(.*?)";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("C:\\log.txt");
        try {
            Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                Matcher m = regex.matcher(line);
                if(m.matches()) {
                    System.out.println(m.group(1));
                }

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `|` is a special regex symbol which means 'or'. So, you have to escape it.

```
public static String pattern = "(.*?)\\|(.*?)\\|(.*?)\\|(.*?)";
```

Answer (score 4):

You can greatly simplify the regex for this.  Since the data appears to be pipe-separated, you should just split on the pipe character. You'll end up with an array of fields which can you further parse as needed:

```
String[] fields = line.split("\\|");
```