# finding matches inside pipes using java regexp

Tags: java, regex, pipe

how do you get the contents of the string inside the pipe?

```
|qwe|asd|zxc|
```

how can I get

```
qwe asd zxc
```

i tried this

```
"\\|{1,}(\\w*)\\|{1,}"
```

and it don't seem to work

i also tried this

```
"\\|{1,}[\\w*]\\|{1,}"
```

it only returns qwe though

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178318/parse-a-string-line-by-opening-a-file-using-regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `String line="|qwe|asd|zxc|";` then
use `string[] fields = line.split("\\|");`
to get array of all your result..

Comment: +1 for using `String.split()` - This method is far simpler than using any complex regex matcher in most cases.

Comment: Some nuance. `fields` size is 5. First and last element are empty. So keep it in mind.

Comment: thanks for the answer sumit. appreciate it :D but I still don't understand why the regexp is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not needed for this but if you insist on using regexes:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\|?(\\w+)\\|");
Matcher m = p.matcher("|qwe|asd|zxc|");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}

/* outputs:
qwe
asd
zxc 
*/
```

---

**Why your regex doesn't work:**

`/\|{1,}(\w*)\|{1,}/` is similar to `/\|(\w*)\|/` and it matches the words between pipes.

Now in your sample string, the first match is `|qwe|`.

Then it continues finding matches in `asd|zxc|`; according to the pattern it skips `asd` and only matches `|zxc|`.

You can fix this by making the preceding pipe optional.

Comment: @simon Not just `Perl`, that was the notation. You could easily use that in `Java`. Edited the answer.

Comment: hey fardjad, thanks for the info and for the free lecture :D thanks again man