# using regexp in java. getting strings around pipes

Tags: java, regex

In a huge way related to [finding matches inside pipes using java regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178539/finding-matches-inside-pipes-using-java-regexp)

I tried getting the string inside the pipes but not around. for example, i input this.

```
|asd|qwe|zxc|||
```

Using split OR some regular expressions, i get

```
result 1 = '',  
result 2 = 'asd',
result 3 = 'qwe',
result 4 = 'zxc',
result 5 = '',
result 6 = ''
```

results 1, 5 and 6 contain 0 length strings and that is ok. but my problem is I can't get a result which would give me the zero length string on the right of the last pipe. I have tried a couple of combinations and I just can't seem to figure it out. Using the string.split method also seems to not get the zero length string on the right side of the last pipe. but it does get the first zero length string on the left side of the first pipe.

Any help, suggestions would be appreciated. I don't mean to make other people do my work, I just need a little help with regex as I am just starting to understand this technology.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the two argument `String.split(String, int)` method with the second argument being -1:

`"|asd|qwe|zxc|||".split("\\|", -1)`

The single argument `split()` method is the same as a call to `split("pattern", 0)` which discards trailing spaces.

Javadoc here:[String.split(String, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: i got it now  If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Not very pretty but..

```
if(yourString.endsWith("|")){
  String toSplit = yourString + "|";
  String[] tokens = toSplit.split("|");
}
```

Comment: :D I am so focused on the regex I forgot to think about workarounds. hey KayKay, thanks for the suggestion. :D :D

Comment: I can try this to other problems i might encounter